# Best method in securing client secret for Authorization Code Flow

Tags: javascript, html, api, oauth, token

From what I understand by looking at Spotify's Authorization Code Flow, it requires a client_id and client_secret to send out a request for an access token and refresh token. If the owner is going to distribute his product that utilizes Spotify API, isn't it dangerous to share their client_secret to the public?

I have also looked at Implicit Grant Flow and it doesn't require a client_secret, however, it only returns one of the two tokens, which is the access token. Wouldn't that be a hassle for the user to constantly authenticate through Spotify's authorization page for every time their access token expires?

Some sources say that the owner could store their secrets in a .env file and retrieve the necessary information that way!

Basically, I am lost and not sure what the best route is without exposing the client secret or preventing users from constantly authenticating themselves. Thanks in advance!

[image: Spotify's Authorization Code Flow]